# Equals heights of thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 `thumbnail span3` elements per Twitter Bootstrap row but the the `<p>` text is variable which breaks the layout. How could I set each `thumbnail` to be the height of the largest thumbnail so that they flow correctly?

```
<div class="box_line" style="float: left; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div class="thumbnail span3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt=""/>
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>Thumbnail label</h5>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I haven't found a working jQuery plugin to do this and the solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143971/using-twitter-bootstrap-2-0-how-to-make-equal-column-heights)  doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your english: What do you mean "everytime the text in the <p> element has else height", and what is "the highest thumbnail" ?

Comment: maybe it could be useful know why do you want all boxes with same height to try different approaches (css pure)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos sometimes the text in the **P** tag can has 10 chars, sometimes 300 chars => the text in the **p** will be in one row, or could be also on 5 rows. "The highest thumbnail" is the thumbnail with the greatest high (because of variable text in the **p**)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan because I try to get [this effect](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/). (this example doesn't works me)

Comment: @user984621 maybe you're trying to get columns height before the complete image load. can you provide a demo of what you've done?

Comment: can you please provide a test case in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Sure, here is it - but I am struggling with how to move three boxes in one row (here on jsfiddle) - [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwqtF/1/)

Comment: And I would like to have the high of the three boxes set up by the greatest hight (in this case by the middle box)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PbfpU/2/ (I used the script you linked in the comments)

anyway be sure to call that function only after all thumbnails have been loaded, otherwise you could get wrong values.

```
function equalHeight(group) {    
    var tallest = 0;    
    group.each(function() {       
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();       
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {          
            tallest = thisHeight;       
        }    
    });    
    group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });
} 

$(document).ready(function() {   
    equalHeight($(".thumbnail")); 
});
```

Comment: but the problem is, that this sample doesn't works in the Chrome - here is set up the height of the row by the first box (in FF it works.)

Comment: hi Fabrizio, could you one more time please send me a fix for Chrome?

Comment: It would be nice to see the code in this answer instead of having to follow a link.

Comment: Instead of `tallest = 0;` it should read `var tallest = 0;`. Otherwise this becomes a global property on the `window` object :-(

Answer (score 17):

I know I'm late to the party, but here's a handy variation on Fabrizio's answer, wrapped up as a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.uniformHeight = function() {
        var maxHeight   = 0,
            max         = Math.max;

        return this.each(function() {
            maxHeight = max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
        }).height(maxHeight);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

...and to use it:

```
$(".thumbnails").find(".thumbnail").uniformHeight();
```

Also, if your thumbnails contain images, make sure to call this after the window load event has fired.

Comment: +1 for the mention about waiting for all images loaded

Answer (score 10):

CSS solution would be to use `clear: left;` for every thumbnail that should be first in the row. This works if you know number of thumbnails in a row beforehand.

I use following css class:

```
ul.thumbnails.per6 > li:nth-child(6n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

And HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails per6">
  <li class="span2">
    <div class="thumbnail">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for browser support.

Answer (score 7):

I liked Tim's answer, and here's my version in a one-liner:

```
$(".thumbnail").height(Math.max.apply(null, $(".thumbnail").map(function() { return $(this).height(); })));
```

With a nod to [Roatin Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/141592) for getting the maximum value of an array.

Comment: This works perfectly, literally plugged it into my bootstrap setup that has an unknown amount of variable height thumbmails. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For responsive sites, you may want to update the height on window resize. I extended Tim Lowrimore's `uniformHeight` plugin with Gaby aka G. Petrioli's clever trick for getting the height of an elements content using wrapInner https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853368/1138558.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.uniformHeight = function () {
        var maxHeight = 0,
            wrapper,
            wrapperHeight;

        return this.each(function () {

            // Applying a wrapper to the contents of the current element to get reliable height
            wrapper = $(this).wrapInner('<div class="wrapper" />').children('.wrapper');
            wrapperHeight = wrapper.outerHeight();

            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, wrapperHeight);

            // Remove the wrapper
            wrapper.children().unwrap();

        }).height(maxHeight);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I then applied it to the thumbnails using:

```
$('.thumbnails').find('.thumbnail').uniformHeight();

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.thumbnails').find('.thumbnail').uniformHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the css flexbox, it's possible to make equals heights of thumbnails with css

Here have best example

```css
.equal-height-thumbnail {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.equal-height-thumbnail li {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0 1% 20px;
  padding:0 0.5%;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
.equal-height-thumbnail figure {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.equal-height-thumbnail figure img{ width:100%;}
.caption { padding: 2%;}
```

```html
<ul class="equal-height-thumbnail">
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget enim et augue mattis tempor nec eget felis. </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget enim et augue mattit felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget enim et augue mattis tempor nec eget felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tempor nec eget felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget enim et augue mattis tempor nec eget felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure><img src="http://www.htmllion.com/img/thumb.jpg" alt="Equal height of thumbnail"></figure>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget enim et augue mattis tempor nabitur </p>
      </div>
    </li>
 
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code in css

```
/*in css*/
  .thumbnail img{
   height:100px;
                }
```

/*or just add it inline*/

```
  <img="imglinkwhateveryouwant" style="height:100px;">
```

that's it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css will fix your issue.

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

You can see the result here.
http://www.bootply.com/RqapUKLqMF

Comment: It's not work. You have just use the same content for all

Answer (score -2):

Just set a maximum height.

```
.caption p {
   height: 120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F5eCq/

Comment: This is non-responsive which defeats the main purpose of using Twitter Bootstrap's `thumbnails` because if the images (among other possible elements) happen to have different heights, the same issue will occur. It's a point of frustration for myself included but this isn't a flexible solution.