# Auto detect height of tallest image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a code for a sliding banner. https://jsfiddle.net/r4ht890f/

Question 1) I'd prefer not to set the height via css for this section and let the javascript code actually control the height of the section.  Is there an easy way to add to the javascript code where it detects the height of the tallest image and sets it somehow so that the image shows up on the page.  Right now, nothing is showing up because the height isn't being detected.

Question 2)  The only other thing I'd like to do to this script is for the last one to naturally go back to the first to form a loop rather than going back through all the old ones to get back to 1.

```
#images_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; 
}
#moving_part {
    width: 100%;

}
#moving_part > div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    float:    left;
}
#moving_part > div img{
    float: left; 
    width:  100%; 
    height: auto;
}
#prev, #next {
    position: absolute;
    cursor:   pointer;
    top:      47%;  
  display:  none; /* hide initially */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
#next{
    right: 0px;
}
#description{
    color:      #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-align: center;
    position:   absolute;
    padding:    15px;
    right:      0;
    left:       0;
  display:    none; /* hide initially */
}

/* EXTRA: navigation */
#navigation{
  display:    none; /* hide initially */
  position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
  text-align:center
}
#navigation span{ /* created by jQuery*/
    display:inline-block;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:4px 10px;
}
```

and here is the javascript

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    var efx  = "slide", // "slide" || "fade"
            animationTime = 600,
            pauseTime = 4000,
      $gal = $("#images_holder"),
        $mov = $("#moving_part"),
        $sli = $mov.find("> div"),
        $btn = $("#prev, #next"),
            $dsc = $("#description"),
            $nav = $("#navigation"), // Our buttons parent
            $navBtns, // Later, our SPAN buttons
            spans = "",
            w = $gal.width(),
            n = $sli.length,
            c = 0,  // Counter // Start index
            itv;    // Interval


for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {     // `n` is the number of slides!
    spans += "<span>"+ (i+1) +"</span>";
}
// Finally append our generated buttons:
$nav.append( spans );
// Retrieve the created buttons and do something on click
$nav.find("span").on("click", function(){
   c = $(this).index(); // Set our counter to the clicked SPAN index
   anim();              // Animate. That easy.
});


    // SETUP (fade or slide?)
    $mov.width(w*n);
    if(efx==="fade") $sli.css({position:"absolute", left:0}).fadeOut(0).eq(c).fadeIn(0);

    function populateDescription() {
        $dsc.text( $sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("alt") );
    }

    function anim() {
        c = c<0 ? n-1 : c%n; // loop-back if exceedds
        populateDescription();
        if (efx==="fade") {
            $sli.fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);
        }else if(efx==="slide") {
            $mov.stop().animate({left: -c*w});
        }
    }

    function auto() {
        $btn.add($dsc).add($nav).stop().fadeOut(); // Hide UI
        itv = setInterval(function(){
           ++c;
           anim();
        }, pauseTime);
    }

    function pause() {
    $btn.add($dsc).add($nav).stop().fadeIn(); // Show UI
        return clearInterval( itv );
    }

  $gal.hover(pause, auto);

    $btn.on("click", function(){
        c = this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c;
        anim();
    });


    populateDescription();
    auto();

});
```

> ```
> <div id="images_holder">
>           <div id="moving_part">
>               <div>
>                   <a href="You-Belong">
> <img src="images/For-Smithfield-Slider-600x232.png" 
> srcset="
> images/For-Smithfield-Slider-1000x387.png 1000w, 
> images/For-Smithfield-Slider-1920x743.png 1920w,
> images/For-Smithfield-Slider-2880x1114.png 2880w
> " alt=""/>
> </a>
>               </div>
>               <div>
>                   <a href="You-Belong">
> <img alt="" src="images/You-Belong-Here-Slider1.png"></a>
>               </div>
>               <div>
>                   <img alt="" src="images/Vision-Statement-01.png">
>               </div>
>           </div>
>
>           <div id="prev">PREV</div>
>           <div id="next">NEXT</div>
>           <div id="description">Test</div>
>           <div id="navigation"></div>
>       </div>
> ```

This is for an active project I am working on and for learning.  I've never done anything like this before.  Any assistance would be great!

Comment: Its really unclear what you're asking and you've posted too much code - please ask one question at a time with just code for that question

Comment: Its two questions and all the code involved. Question 1: I want the images to show without setting height. I would like javascript to determine max image height and use that.   Question 2: I'd like slide 4 to naturally transition to slide 1 to form a loop.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you make a fiddle and I'm happy to have a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r4ht890f/  Here you go.  And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this help for question 1: [Equals heights of thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278569/equals-heights-of-thumbnails)

Add some custom class to your images and that code should work changing .thumbnail to .yourcustomclass.