# Make columns the same height in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three columns inside a row. I want all three columns to have the same height (fill the entire white space out)

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the left column is the correct height. Where the middle and the right aren't.

The scaffolding of it looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      -- menu --
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
     -- gray content --
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
     -- black content--
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to give the middle and the right span height of 100%, but that doesn't do it. Can anybody guide me in the correct direction?

I am using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: You're missing `>` in the end of first tag - `<div class="container"`.

Comment: "The latest version of Twitter Bootstrap" is slightly ambiguous at the moment - do you mean the stable 2.3.2, or the 3.0.0-RC2 branch?

Comment: Do you know which of the columns is the longest?

Comment: @ItayItai Yes, the --menu-- (span3) is longest.

Comment: If you know the menu is always the longest, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solve this without JS.
Just use

```
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
position: absolute; /* The container must have position: relative */
```

It does magic :)

An example I've made:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/E8SK6/1

Result:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/E8SK6/1/show/

**Edit**:

Since you said on a comment that the menu is always the biggest, you can use this new example:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/E8SK6/5/

If you don't know which one of them is the longest, maybe the answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375692/make-two-columns-the-same-height?lq=1) is better. It uses display: table-cell. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTNeB/2/)'s the example

Comment: The position is set to absolute, though in your comments you write it must be set ti relative. What should I use? :-)

Comment: The inner positions are absolute but the wrapper element is relative

Answer (score 19):

I found this solution for bootstrap 3 which works great for me

http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

It uses these styles:

```
/* columns of same height styles */
.container-xs-height {
    display:table;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
.row-xs-height {
    display:table-row;
}
.col-xs-height {
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-sm-height {
        display:table;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
    }
    .row-sm-height {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .col-sm-height {
        display:table-cell;
        float:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-md-height {
        display:table;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
    }
    .row-md-height {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .col-md-height {
        display:table-cell;
        float:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-lg-height {
        display:table;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
    }
    .row-lg-height {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .col-lg-height {
        display:table-cell;
        float:none;
    }
}
/* vertical alignment styles */
.col-top {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.col-middle {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.col-bottom {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

And this markup

```
<div class="container container-xs-height">
    <div class="row row-xs-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-height"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-height col-top"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-height col-middle"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-height col-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting Bootstrap specific solution. This one seems to be the best so far.

Comment: Agree, this solution seems the best one for me.

Comment: @alex in what context?

Answer (score 2):

Ah this is an age old issue.

If you set 100% height on an element, it's parent needs a set height for it to go off. Since the div.row has a fluid height, that won't work.

The way around this would be:

Set a fixed height on the `div.row` (probably not a good idea if you want a fluid design)

or

Use jQuery to do it:

HTML

```
<div class="row equalHeight">
    <div class="span3">
      -- menu --
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
     -- gray content --
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
     -- black content--
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.equalHeight').each(function() {
  var eHeight = $(this).innerHeight();

  $(this).find('div').outerHeight(eHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, is possible with `row-eq-height`

**LINK:** http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: As a note, this uses flexbox, which isn't support in IE9 or below.