# Css How to make a div same high with individual footer?

Tags: css, css-tables

I have this, and I want to fill dynamically this divs, but the height of the div panel-row-text are not equal, I want all have the same height (will take the bigger height) and I want the footer will be same level or row.
I was trying all ways but can't figure it out.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div  class=panel-row>
        <div class="panel-row-Text">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-row-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=panel-row>
        <div class="panel-row-Text">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-row-footer">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class=panel-row>
        <div class="panel-row-Text">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-row-footer">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class=panel-row>` should be `<div class="panel-row">`

Comment: you'll either have to use javascript for this or an actual table

Comment: I was trying to do a div table cell but not success...I really dont want to use JQ or JS...is not clean...any other opinion? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this JavaScript + jQuery solution. Though ugly, it works with legacy browsers.

```
 // Equalize the height of front page boxes
function tuneFrontPage() {

    //
    $('.frontpage-promo .well').height(function () {
        var maxHeight = $('.frontpage-promo .well').max( function () { return $(this).height(); });
        return maxHeight;
    });
}
```

Pick it up from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189443/315168

CSS3 flexbox might be a modern solution for this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/ (check compatibility from caniuse.com for your target audience)