# How to set each column same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Help me, how to set each column same height? I have this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the content displayed is as follows:
[image]

But when I try to resize the browser window, the content is shifted wrong:
[image]

And so should:
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020360/bootstrap-how-to-get-a-column-with-100-the-height-of-another-column?rq=1

Comment: min-height min-height

Comment: @knitevision, What do you mean?

Comment: @Pearson sorry i thought you mean having same height o_O

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add a `clearfix` that's only visible on the smaller viewports..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/ZDDbPlCraT

Answer (score -1):

create a custom css class in your .css file

```
.fixed-height {
height: 200px;
}
```

Then add this to your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fixed-height">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fixed-height">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fixed-height">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fixed-height">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could get more complex and customise the fixed-height class based on screen size - but above works across all situations

Comment: umm... sorry but this works, and addresses the question exactly so why the downvote? http://www.bootply.com/QCh2TiB8cx