# How to make right side bar height go along with the height of the main content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap framework and CSS.

I want my right sidebar height to go along with the height of my main content. How should I do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="includes/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <header class="margin-top">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <img border=0 src="images/header.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact&nbsp;</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about-us.php">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.well -->
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="span9">
                        <div class="hero-unit">
                            If I have a long content here.. The sidebar does not follow the height of the content.
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div><!--/.fluid-container-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some more description to your question?

Comment: Check the acepted answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143971/using-twitter-bootstrap-2-0-how-to-make-equal-column-heights/14004830#14004830

Answer (score 0):

your container seems to be fine and has a auto height so what is the problem
here you see the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/ZpZCD/

```
.container {background-color:#fc0;}
```