# Make equal height columns and vertically aligned caption in Bootstrap 2.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Expanding on this question on [how to make equal height columns in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9143971/1366033) ([original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/4Pyhj/)).
Now the column heights match, but I need to make the captions vertically align at the bottom.

Here is a [**new fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ProfitGuider/dTxSb/4/).

As you can see the H2 captions do not line up.
Here's how I want it to look:

[image: demo]

Starting a new with: `<div class="row-fluid col-wrap">` does not work because the captions separate from the text at media breaks.

Comment: It might be useful if you add a link to the question that you continue from if you mention it in a question.

Comment: I don't see any H2 columns in your fiddle... What do you mean by this?

Comment: Trevor:  Thank you.  I did not realize jsfiddle changes the url when an update is made.  New link is in question and here - http://jsfiddle.net/ProfitGuider/dTxSb/4/

Comment: Alexey:  Thanks.  I added the link to original question and the fiddle referenced therein.

Comment: Here is a link to a picture showing the caption/title vertically centered along the bottom of the row.  This how we'd like it to look.   http://www.electronicsmarketinginc.com/images/jaggy2.jpg

Answer (score 17):

## The Problem

The problem is, the answer from the original question pretty much sets the height of each of those divs to infinite.  After the content, the div just stretches on and on.

The downside of which, is we **don't know where the bottom of this element is.**

*The padding is sized to content:
                      
But the element stretches forever*

[image: sizing]

---

## A Solution

One element that **does know** where the element ends is the wrapper. That was it's job.  So what we'd like to do is position our header tag relative to the `.col-wrap` container.

To position an element relative to it's grandparent, we'll set the grandchild `position` to `absolute`.  This will position relative to the first parent element it finds with `position` equal to `relative`.  So we can set the header to the bottom of the `col-wrap` container with the following code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row-fluid col-wrap">
    <div class="span4 col well">
        <p>left column</p>
        <h2>Title or Caption</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.col-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.col-wrap > .col > h2{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

One thing we have to adjust for is now that the header is positioned absolutely, it's taken out of the document flow and no longer occupies any space.  A hackish way to get around this is to double up your header tags and use one as a placeholder.

**HTML**

```
<h2 class='absolute'>Title or Caption</h2>
<h2 class='relative'>Title or Caption</h2>
```

Quick CSS Overview:

```css
visibility: hidden; /* hides an element but still takes up the same space*/
display: none;      /* hides an element and collapses*/
```

Using that:

- On a  big screen, we'll use the relative header as a placeholder by setting the `visibility` to `hidden` and positioning the absolute header at the bottom of it's grandparent.
- On a small screen, we'll just collapse the absolute header, since we don't need absolute positioning anymore so the first will still be inline and we don't need both.

In CSS, it will look like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col > h2.absolute{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .col > h2.relative{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col > h2.absolute{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

---

**Finally**, since the `h2` element is positioned absolutely, the column no longer acts like a container to prevent the text from spilling over.  We can fix this by applying some sizing constraints on our visible absolutely positioned elements.  These should be done to mimic the placeholder constraints so they line up.

We can apply a `span4` class to the absolute header as well as the following css

```html
<h2 class='absolute span4'>Title or Caption</h2>
```

```css
.col > h2.absolute{
    margin-left:0;
    padding-right:40px;
}
```

---

## Demo

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/3L84c/)

It will look like this:

[image: demo]

Comment: WOW.  I'm so impressed and thankful.  Really appreciate the thorough explanation, for example, the relative and absolute settings.  Wish I had enough rep to vote this answer up.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Remember to [mark as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the response which best answers your question, for this, and other, questions you post here on StackOverflow.