# 2 100% columns + sticky footer

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a website, here it is: http://www.testeeee.cixx6.com/

And I can't put the site_contente, and the content and sidebar (this 2 are inside site_contente) 100% height.

Basically I want the content and the sidebar to be 100% no matter what. And when the content on content div is more than 100%, I want it to scroll, I mean, only scroll on content scroll.

Example of what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2rid.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you submitted, you'll need to user an iframe.  However, you may be referring to something like this: [How might I force a floating DIV to match the height of another floating DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526294/how-might-i-force-a-floating-div-to-match-the-height-of-another-floating-div)

Comment: that seems to complicated. and if the scroll goes to the normal place, but the only div that still scrolling is the content?

Comment: No veo lo que quieres decir. ¿Español?

Answer (score 0):

to set scroll in a DIV use the style properties

```
overflow:scroll|auto
overflow-x: scroll|auto
overflow-y: scroll|auto
```

for sizeing I think you are answered

Edit ¿have you even tried???:

Copying from the question that was refered in other answer:

```
<DIV id="site_content" >

<DIV id="content" style="float : left; width :65%; height:auto;background-color:#FDD017;">
</DIV>

<DIV id="side_bar" style="float : left; width :35%;height:auto; background-color:#FDD017;">
</DIV>

</DIV>
```

Comment: my problem now is not the scroll. 1st i want to put the sidebar and the content, that are both inside of site_content div 100%, so they go down and stick to the footer

Comment: but that will do what? put the divs on 100%?

Comment: After trying you will see what it does.

Comment: and i dont change nothing on the css? i mean that will scale the container and sidebar like put content 65% or site content, and sidebar 35%, right? and by the way, the site_content is inside of "main" div.